# Arduino and ZMPT101B But Not Stable Sigma Output In 7segment Display(TM1637) using filter library

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sensors, library, 7-segment

````
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <math.h>
//TRUE RMS START
#include <Filters.h> //Easy library to do the calculations
#include <TM1637Display.h>
float testFrequency = 100;                     // test signal frequency (Hz)
float windowLength = 100.0 / testFrequency;   // how long to average the signal, for statistist
int Sensor = 0; //Sensor analog input, here it's A0
int Sensor2 = 0; //Sensor analog input, here it's A1

float intercept = -0.04; // to be adjusted based on calibration testing
float slope = 0.0405; // to be adjusted based on calibration testing
float current_Volts, output_volts; // Voltage

unsigned long printPeriod = 500; //Refresh rate
unsigned long previousMillisTRUE = 0;
int truermsflag = 0;
int inputvolt = 0, outputvolt = 0;
RunningStatistics inputStats;
RunningStatistics inputStats2;
int sigmaint = 0;
//TRUE RMS end
//#define cbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) &= ~_BV(bit))
//#define sbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) |= _BV(bit))

// Module connection pins (Digital Pins)
#define CLK 3
#define DIO 2

#define CLK1 4
#define DIO1 5

#define switcht 6
#define Relay1 8
#define Relay2 9
#define Relay3 10
#define Relay4 11
#define TRelay 12
// The amount of time (in milliseconds) between tests
int i = 0;
int timerflag = 0, onetimeflag = 0;
int volt = 0, voltoutput = 0;
TM1637Display display(CLK, DIO);
TM1637Display display2(CLK1, DIO1);
const uint8_t DONE[] =
{
    //SEG_B | SEG_C | SEG_D | SEG_E | SEG_G,           // d
    SEG_D,   // O
    //SEG_C | SEG_E | SEG_G,                           // n
    //SEG_A | SEG_D | SEG_E | SEG_F | SEG_G            // E
};
const uint8_t Dely[] =
{
    SEG_B | SEG_C | SEG_D | SEG_E | SEG_G,           // d
    SEG_A | SEG_D | SEG_E | SEG_F | SEG_G,           // E
    SEG_F | SEG_E | SEG_D,                           // L
    SEG_F | SEG_B | SEG_G | SEG_C // Y
};
const uint8_t HIVOLT[] =
{
    SEG_F | SEG_E | SEG_B | SEG_C | SEG_G,           // H
    //SEG_B | SEG_C,           // I
    //SEG_F | SEG_E | SEG_D | SEG_C | SEG_B, // V
};

const uint8_t L0VOLT[] =
{
    SEG_F | SEG_E | SEG_D,                           // L
    //SEG_A | SEG_B | SEG_C | SEG_D | SEG_E | SEG_F,//0
    //SEG_F | SEG_E | SEG_D | SEG_C | SEG_B  ,// V


};

int ledPin =  13;      // the number of the LED pin
unsigned long previousMillis1 = 0, previousMillis2 = 0, previousMillis3 = 0;      // will store last time LED was updated
//unsigned long currentMillis;
unsigned long previousmacro = 0;
unsigned long currentMacro = 0;
int acVoltage(int adcpin);
int average(int pin);

void setup()
{
    //
    //  sbi(ADCSRA, ADPS2);
    //  cbi(ADCSRA, ADPS1);
    //  cbi(ADCSRA, ADPS0);
    analogReference(EXTERNAL);  // set ADC positive reference voltage to 1.1V (internal)
    pinMode(switcht, INPUT);
    pinMode(switcht, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(Relay1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Relay2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Relay3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Relay4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(TRelay, OUTPUT);

    //For Optocuplar Relay
    digitalWrite(Relay1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Relay2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Relay3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Relay4, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(TRelay, HIGH);

    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

    display.setBrightness(0x0f);
    display2.setBrightness(0x0f);
    //display.setSegments(Dely);

    //  delay(3000);
    //  display.clear();
    //  display.setSegments(HIVOLT, 3, 0);
    //
    //  delay(3000);
    //  display.clear();
    //  display.setSegments(L0VOLT, 3, 0);


    //display2.setSegments(Dely);
    //display.clear();
    Serial.begin(57600);


    //delay(1000);
}

void loop()
{
    if (truermsflag == 0)
    {
        //TRUE RMS

        truermsflag = 1;
        //END TRUE RMS
    }
    unsigned long currentMac = micros();

    if (currentMac - previousMillis3 > 3)
    {
        previousMillis3 = currentMac;
        //Easy life lines, actual calculation of the RMS requires a load of coding

        inputStats.setWindowSecs( windowLength );
        inputStats2.setWindowSecs( windowLength );
        Sensor = analogRead(A0);  // read the analog in value:
        Sensor2 = analogRead(A1);  // read the analog in value:
        inputStats.input(Sensor);  // log to Stats function
        inputStats2.input(Sensor2);  // log to Stats function

        //Serial.println("run") ;

    }


    if ((unsigned long)(millis() - previousMillisTRUE) >= printPeriod)
    {
        previousMillisTRUE = millis();   // update time every second
        current_Volts = intercept + slope * inputStats.sigma(); //Calibartions for offset and amplitude
        current_Volts = current_Volts * (56.613);             //Further calibrations for the amplitude
        inputvolt = round(current_Volts);
        Serial.print(" START ");
        Serial.print("Input Volts:");
        Serial.println(inputvolt);
        Serial.print("Input Sigma");
        Serial.println(inputStats.sigma());
        Serial.println(" END ");
        output_volts = intercept + slope * inputStats2.sigma();
        output_volts = output_volts * (56.613);
        outputvolt = round(output_volts);
        //Serial.print("Output Volts:");
        //Serial.println(outputvolt);

    }

    //end
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis3 > 1000)
    {
        // save the last time you blinked the LED
        previousMillis3 = currentMillis;
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

        // display.showNumberDec(inputvolt, false, 3, 1);

    }

    /*
      unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

        if ((currentMillis - previousMillis1 > 1000) && timerflag == 0) {
          previousMillis1 = currentMillis;
          digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);


          if ((digitalRead(switcht) == LOW) && timerflag == 0 && onetimeflag == 0) {

            i = 10;
            onetimeflag = 1;
          }
          if ((digitalRead(switcht) == HIGH) && timerflag == 0 && onetimeflag == 0) {

            i = 180;
            onetimeflag = 1;

          }
          display2.showNumberDec(i--);
          if (i == 0) {
            digitalWrite(TRelay, LOW);
            timerflag = 1;
          }
        }
        //Timer Relay Function END

        //ADC Functions

        //display.setSegments(HIVOLT, 1, 0);

    if (timerflag == 1) {
          display2.showNumberDec(outputvolt, false, 3, 1); // Expect: _14_

          if (outputvolt > 245) {
            display2.setSegments(HIVOLT, 1, 0);
            digitalWrite(TRelay, HIGH);
          }
          else if (outputvolt <= 180) {
            display2.setSegments(L0VOLT, 1, 0);
            digitalWrite(TRelay, HIGH);
          } else {
            display2.setSegments(DONE, 1, 0);
            digitalWrite(TRelay, LOW);
          }
        }

    */

    if (240 < current_Volts)
    {

        digitalWrite(Relay1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Relay2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Relay3, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Relay4, HIGH);
    }
    if ((90 <= current_Volts) && (current_Volts <= 120))
    {
        digitalWrite(Relay1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Relay2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Relay3, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Relay4, LOW);

    }
    if ((121 <= current_Volts) && (current_Volts <= 150))
    {
        digitalWrite(Relay1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Relay2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Relay3, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Relay4, HIGH);

    }
    if ((151 <= current_Volts) && (current_Volts <= 240))
    {
        digitalWrite(Relay1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Relay2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Relay3, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Relay4, HIGH);
    }
    //ITimer2.init();
    //ITimer1.init();
    // ITimer1.attachInterruptInterval(TIMER2_INTERVAL_MS, TimerHandler2);
    //ITimer2.attachInterruptInterval(TIMER2_INTERVAL_MS, TimerHandler2);
}

int acVoltage(int adcpin)
{
    int adcvalue = 0, returnresult = 0;
    unsigned long sum = 0, avg = 0, squre = 0;
    double root = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {

        unsigned long currentMacro = micros();
        unsigned long currentMillis;
        if ((currentMacro - previousmacro > 2000))
        {
            previousmacro = currentMillis;

            adcvalue = average(adcpin);
        }
        squre = (long)adcvalue * adcvalue;
        //delayMicroseconds(667);
        sum += squre;
    }

    avg = (long)sum / 10;
    //Serial.print("after average of squre");
    //Serial.println(avg);
    root = sqrt(avg);
    returnresult = (int)root;
    return returnresult;
}


int average(int pin)
{
    int sum = 0;
    float avg = 0;
    int val = 0;
    int funsend;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        val = analogRead(pin);
        sum += val;

    }

    avg = (float)sum / 5;
    funsend = round(avg);
    //Serial.print(" average function");
    //Serial.println(avg);
    //Serial.print("Value");
    //Serial.println(funsend);
    //delay(20);
    return funsend;

}
</code>```
````

Comment: Please describe what you mean when you say "not stable".